# Get datas from one to many (inverse ) relation laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-blade

I have 2 models 'Trips.php'

```
public function region() 
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Region');
}
```

`Region.php`

```
public function trips()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Trip');
}
```

I'm trying to show the trips that are in one one specific region. For example: I have a region named `Lake Side` and I want to show all trips that are in `Lake Side` region in list.

I tried the following:

In controller:

```
$trips = Trip::all();
```

In view:

```
@foreach($trips as $trip)
<li><a href="#">
    {{$trip->region->name}}</a>
    <ul class="dropdown">
        <li><a href="#">
            {{$trip->title}}</a>
        </li>    
    </ul>
</li>
@endforeach
```

This gives me region name and trip name but repeats region name if more than one trip is made in same region.

And tried another way around (inverse):

```
<ul class="dropdown">
@foreach($regions as $region)
<li><a href="#">
    {{$region->tour->title}}</a>
</li>
@endforeach
</ul>
```

And getting error `Trying to get property of non-object`

Answer (score 0):

By getting trips with regions, what you're essentially getting is every trip with a region property.

Instead do the reverse `Region::with('trips')->where('id', $regionId)->get()` and you'll get regions with their trips. So now every region result has a trips property which contains many trips.

Alternatively don't use eager load. So `Region::firstOrFail($regionId)` then just use `$region->trips`.

And you can loop through them like

```
// Can print region here
@foreach($region->trips as $trip)
    // Can print region's trips here
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do that is to use [`whereHas()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence):

```
$trips = Trip::whereHas('region', function($q) use ($regionName) {
    $q->where('name', $regionName);
})->get();
```

Pass `$trips` and `$regionName` to the view:

```
@foreach ($trips as $trip)
    <li><a href="#">{{ $regionName }}</a>
        <ul class="dropdown">
            <li><a href="#">
                {{ $trip->title }}</a>
            </li>    
        </ul>
    </li>
@endforeach
```

Alternatively, you can use [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading):

```
$region = Region::where('name', $regionName)->with('trips')->first();
```

And in the view:

```
@foreach ($region->trips as $trip)
    <li><a href="#">{{ $region->name }}</a>
        <ul class="dropdown">
            <li><a href="#">
                {{ $trip->title }}</a>
            </li>    
        </ul>
    </li>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Is it possible to do it in service provider ?? As I'm trying to make navigation bar.